# Type initialization with jackson?

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I'm working on data class extension with polymorphic property. Here's the dataclass:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo

data class CarModelResponse(
    val models: List<CarType> = listOf(),
)

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(MercedesType::class, name = "mercedes"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(OpelType::class, name = "opel"),
)
abstract class CarType(open val type: String) {
    abstract fun getCarFeature(): Any
}

data class MercedesType(
    val comfortClass: Int
) : CarType("mercedes") {
    override fun getCarFeature(): Int = comfortClass
}

data class OpelType(
    val coupon: String
) : CarType("opel") {
    override fun getCarFeature(): String = coupon
}
```

and also i have a test, where i'm trying to get a typed car variable:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class CarResponseTest {

    @Test
    fun getCarFeatures() {
        val json: String = """
            {
                "models": [
                    {
                        "type": "mercedes",
                        "comfortClass": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "opel",
                        "coupon": "Buy Opel and win a Mercedes! Coupon #1."
                    }
                ]
            }""".trimIndent()
        val response = jacksonObjectMapper().readValue<CarModelResponse>(json)
        val comfortClass: Int = (response.models.first() as MercedesType).getCarFeature()
        val couppon: String = (response.models.last() as OpelType).getCarFeature()
    }
}
```

Deserialization works fine, but I need to retrieve car's feature without casting with `as` at last two lines of code, but I'm a little stuck how to do that. Could anyone advice how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with no casting, because compiler needs to know what type must be assigned, however in this case you can avoid casting to `MercedesType` or `OpelType`:

```kotlin
val comfortClass: Int = response.models.first().getCarFeature() as Int
val coupon: String = response.models.last().getCarFeature() as String
```